# Multi-threading in Web Application (WCF / WebAPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an "engine" that I want to expose via an HTTP layer (hosted with WebAPI / WCF).

This engine does some simple read only operations on large volumes of data and can really benefit from parallelism. A simple switch from for(...) to Parallel.For(...) does wonders.

Now I think we shouldn't do these kind of multi-threading in a web server, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to host this.

Ideally I'd like this to be hosted in IIS as a standard web app either with WebAPI or WCF. If this is not a good solution, what would be a good alternative?

Would it be to better to self host WebAPI or WCF in a standard Windows Service? I'm not sure if the issues here are IIS or ASP.NET specific.

Or maybe this is not a problem and I'm just worrying too much?

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what your concerns are but I'll try to give you some basis on which you can decide:

**You can use multithreading in IIS/ASP.NET safely.** Of course, with many parallel request you don't need that because the parallelism happens at a higher level (in fact, thoughput will slightly suffer, but only slightly). With few parallel requests though you can reduce latency using parallelism at a lower level (`Parallel.For`).

So multi-threading in ASP.NET is more about reducing latency than increasing throughput.

I don't see how self-hosting would change any of this.

You seem to have a little diffuse concerns that this is a viable approach. Try to formulate specific concerns and I'll address them.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the poorly defined question. I was under the impression (and having trouble finding references now) that by creating threads in a web app we are allocating threads from the same thread pool that IIS uses to serve requests. Thus, if we increase the number of concurrent users, we are much more likely to exhaust the thread pool, which basically stops IIS from serving new requests. Now if the 2 thread pools are not the same, this is obviously not applicable. Does it make more sense?

Comment: a) The thread pool for ASP.NET and for tasks is the same but that is not a problem as long as the application is not overloaded. If it is overloaded this is a problem anyway that you need to solve regardless of threading. Parallelism does not make overloading (significantly) worse. b) You can use a 2nd thread pool using the TaskScheduler API but that does not solve the overloading. Does not help. Any other concerns I should address?